# RewriteRule for the dynamic part of url which is not permanent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/id([0-9]+)/?$ /?page=$1&id=$2&location=$3 [L]
```

I need to make a rule for the part &location=

This part of url &location= is not permanent. The url originally presented without &location= but some links will include with part and I need to add it to the RewriteRule.

I was trying to do this way

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/id([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /?page=$1&id=$2&location=$3 [L]
```

But in this case the url like this

```
http://www.example.com/travel/id725
```

not found without 3-rd parameter. But I need it to work both ways

```
http://www.example.com/travel/id725
AND
example.com/travel/id725/43
```

Can you help me with it please?

Comment: Example URLS should'n contain site.com. Use example.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two different rules. First, when all three parameters are present; and then for the case where only two parameters are present.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/id(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ /?page=$1&id=$2&location=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/id(\d+)/?$ /?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: It's pity I can't vote up +1.. it requires 15 reputation and I have less :( But I'm really happy with your awesome answer!